# Change outline level to Body Text in python-docx

Tags: python-docx

I have this code:

```
  for para in doc.paragraphs:
    if para.style.name != 'Heading 1':
        #Change outline level of para to Body Text
```

I'd like to change outline level of para to 'Body Text'.
I must create an index in a huge docx document.
I want that only paragraph with 'Heading 1' will be in index so I think I must set other paragraphs outline level Body Text or in a way to not appear in index.

Answer (score 1):

The outline-level for headings is an attribute of the style, so changing the style to `Body Text` should do what you're looking for:

```
paragraph.style = document.styles['Body Text']
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but some paragraphs now don't have same formatting (e.g. don't have bold anymore). Can I change only the level?

Comment: I must create an index in a huge docx document. I want that only paragraph with 'Heading 1' will be in index so I think I must set other paragraphs outline level Body Text or in a way to not appear in index.

Comment: A paragraph style includes character formatting, like typeface, bold or italic, and font size. When you change the style of a paragraph, it gets the character formatting of the new style (although individually bold or italicized words should remain that way). If you want a Heading 1 paragraph to _look_ the same but not have the outline level, create a _new_ style (maybe "Bold Body") with the desired character formatting and use that. By default a new style won't have an outline level. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html#add-or-delete-a-style

Comment: My problem is that any other paragraph not 'Heading 1' can have any style. In substance I want only 'Heading 1' in index and no other paragraph but I don't want that the paragraph looses style. Maybe for every paragraph say 'p' not having style 'Heading 1' I must create a new style with same fomatting but without any level.
I tried your comment in this link: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/746

outlineLvls = paragraph._p.xpath(".//w:outlineLvl")
for outlineLvl in outlineLvls:
    outlineLvl.getparent().remove(outlineLvl)

but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is my adapted code:

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name != 'Heading 1':
        outlineLvls = paragraph._p.xpath(".//w:outlineLvl")
        for outlineLvl in outlineLvls:
            outlineLvl.getparent().remove(outlineLvl)